# Difference between CAST(DateColumn AS DATE) and DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, DateColumn()), 0)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I would like to know the difference between

```
SELECT CAST(DateColumn AS DATE)
```

and

```
SELECT DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, DateColumn()), 0)
```

I have calculation which is long winded that looks like this:

```
sum(case when DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,ModifiedOn), 0) between DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0) AND DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0) -7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [0-7 Days]
```

I would like to know what the different are between the above combination of DateAdd and DateDiff (which is widely used to strip off the time) compare to just `Cast(DateColumn as Date)`?

Would there be a difference? for me it looks the same but just wanted to be sure they both do the same thing so going forward I can implement the latter.

The ModifiedOn Column is a DateTime type

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both do the same thing.

SQL Server introduced the `date` data type in version 2008.  In previous versions, there was no "convenient" way to remove the time component from a `datetime` value.  The solution was to calculate the number of days from some canonical point in time (say, "0") and then add those number of days back.

Comment: Thank you, just needed clarification and confirmation